# Last Row in a Range - last row is NOT last used row on entire sheet

Tags: excel, range, vba

I've looked around for how to find the last row in a range, but the answer I found could - at best - only give me the last used row of the entire sheet.

For example, let's say I have elements in `A1:A10`, `B6:B9`, and `C1:C4`.  I'd like to find the last row in columns `B:C`.  In this case the answer should be row 9.  I've tried using `SpecialCells(xlLastCell)`, but have only gotten an answer of row 10.

I'm sure there's a very easy answer, but I can't find it!  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can return the number of the last row in columns `B:C` with VBA:

```
Sub ReturnLastRow()
    MsgBox "Last row in columns B:C is " & _
        WorksheetFunction.Max(ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row, ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row)
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh, cool!  I'm pretty sure that's exactly what I'm looking for.  I'm excited to test it tomorrow!

Comment: @SørenHoltenHansen, thanks!  Just got to try it.  Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

For any range **r**:

```
nLastRow = r.Rows.Count + r.Row - 1
MsgBox ("last row " & nLastRow)

nLastColumn = r.Columns.Count + r.Column - 1
MsgBox ("last column " & nLastColumn)

nFirstRow = r.Row
MsgBox ("first row " & nFirstRow)

nFirstColumn = r.Column
MsgBox ("first column " & nFirstColumn)

numrow = r.Rows.Count
MsgBox ("number of rows " & numrow)

numcol = r.Columns.Count
MsgBox ("number of columns " & numcol)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the last row in a specific Range, not necessarily a specific row, you can simply reference the very last cell in that range similar to how you would do it with an array:

```
Set RR = Range("B6:B9", "C4:C11")
MsgBox "The Last Row is " & RR(RR.Count).Row
```

OR

```
Set RR = Range("B6:B11", "C4:C8")
MsgBox "The Last Row is " & RR(RR.Count).Row
```

Both will return 11 as the last row in the above example.